# how to configure apache nifi on https

Tags: apache-nifi

1) http and no-dns (working)

I was using nifi on http, and it was working fine. at that time I was accessing it via ip or server name itself. everything was working fine.

2) https (self signed) and no-dns (working)

i did https setup using toolkit and it worked, although chrome kept showing red color message. which was expected. but atleast things worked.

3) dns (internal) + signed certificate (external authority (Symantec))

dns works fine, as I am able to ping the box using dns. also i added this dns to etc host file.

even though nifi is internal to org, I still went head and bought a certificate. and CNAME i used was the dns name of my server.

certificate i got was a chained certificate

`my_dns_>TrustedSecureCertificateAuthority5>USERTrustRSAAddTrustCA>AddTrustExternalCARoot`

I create a JKS, and added all of them in it, also added a key_pair to JKS, and I appended all certificated to key_pair too.

Then I changed nifi.properties and used same jks as trust-store and key-store.

now if i use nifi with new dns and https, i am getting "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" (attached image) on Chrome. On IE, i get a TLS error. so I dont think thr is something wrong either with certificate or browser.

[image]

if I give url as (see image) https://server_name:9447/nifi, nifi opens up..with but still shows up red color warning, but this time is not for self signed certificate, but for name not matching. which confirms that nifi web server has access to my new jks, and it also reads it...but then why it is not working?

[image]

what am i missing here? can nifi run on externally bought certificate? or it always has to work with self-signed certificate?

if you are running nifi with external certified certificate, please share your configuration.

do I still have to use toolkit? or toolkit does same thing, which i did by buying the certificate? if true, what am i missing here?

Comment: Just to confirm, the certificate Common Name, the nifi.properties nifi.web.https.host value and the browser URL you're entering all use the same domain name? They're all "dev.nifi.X"?

Comment: yes, they are same.

Comment: Is there a stacktrace in the NiFi nifi-app.log for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is how i resolved it.

after nothing worked. I went back to https setup of nifi, where nifi generates keystore and truststore jks.

and then i downloaded both, and edited it. I removed all previous certificates (self signed one). and then added my CA certificate chain.

then simply uploaded them back. then just restarted nifi.

nifi is now on https.